# com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE android 9 (sdk 28) doesn't work

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm, android-9.0-pie

I'm having issues with the new Android-SDK 28 from Google. (Android Pie)

I'm trying to send a **c2dm** cloud message (push notification), everything works fine on 
API level lower or equal to 27 (tested with real phones and simulator), but on API level 28, it fails - the `onReceive` is not called on a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver` that handles the broadcast.

I've been reading everything I could find on this issue, but to no avail, any useful hints are welcome.

EDIT2: uploaded example project: https://ufile.io/qb3uu
You need to edit the `SENDER_ID` in `GCMIntentService` with your key. As far as I know, the only way to get a GCM key is to have one already as Google disabled the access to a working console a while ago.

Comment: Is this broadcast receiver declared in manifest or registered in runtime?

Comment: It is declared in the manifest, but i can re-register it at runtime, just a sec to test it.
`GCMBroadcastReceiver receiver = new GCMBroadcastReceiver();
//   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
//   filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
//   filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION");
//   filter.addCategory("com.myapp");
//   registerReceiver(receiver, filter, "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND", null);`

Is this ok? @Pawel

Comment: GCM has already been deprecated, you should use FCM

Comment: @Saurabh I'm fixing an abandoned project from my company, and the server cannot be updated until December. This is why we need to fix android 9 first, then fix the server, then give an update with FCM. Currently this is the issue i need to resolve.

Comment: @Pawel, tested with the above code - this is set on `onCreate()` but with no luck.

Comment: Also tested the BroadcastReceiver with adb like so : `./adb shell am broadcast -c com.myapp -a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE -e data "SomeData"` (while disabling the SEND permission) and it works on Android 9 - so the mechanism is not broken, seems like the cloud messages are just not delivered to the Android Pie devices. I'm stuck. Help!

Comment: Updating to `FCM` on server is not a big deal, Just you need to update endpoint **URL** to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: @KhaledLela, we already did that, we already have the fix on both client and server side, we just can't send the update just yet, politics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
String token = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.